# Rotate a fragment in devices with width 600dp and higher

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an app which the screen rotation is locked in it for `BaseActivity` with is the parent for all views with this code in the manifest :

```
android:configChanges="uiMode"
```

So all fragments and activities are vertical and cannot be rotated.

I need to create a fragment that will bind to this activity and needs to be rotated on devices with a width of 600dp or higher and displayed in horizontal mode. When the fragment is destroyed(or the view is destroyed) things need to go the way they were. The activity and all fragments should be displayed vertically.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit**
This is the code I added in the fragment, but the fragment gets laggy and a black balnk screen shows eventually.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false).apply {
            post {
                if (measuredWidth > 600) {
                    activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
}
```

Comment: In your fragment onCreate( ), check if the device is larger width. If yes, then handle the orientation changes. In your fragments onDestroy( ) again revert the orientation changes you have earlier made. Did you try this approach? Can you post your code, let us see what you have tried.

Comment: Yes I did, I'll post the code now. @Rajasekhar

Comment: @Rajasekhar just added an edit containing the code

Comment: I have added my answer., let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume you are using `NavigationComponent` you can handle all orientation and check for width in activity itself.

I have created boolean resource value for both regular and larger devices.

`values\bools.xml` This is for regular devices

**We set this to false intentionally, because we know the width is small**

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isLarger">false</bool>
</resources>
```

`values-sw600dp/bools.xml` This is for larger devices. You need to create this file.

**We set this to true, because we know the width is large now**

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isLarger">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Now in your activity or fragment, when you do this check calling this resource, if the app is running in mobile it will return false. If tablet or larger devices it will return true.

With `NavigationComponent` and `destinationListener` you can handle everything here.

```
       navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.firstFragment -> {
                    requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                }

                R.id.secondFragment -> {
                    if (resources.getBoolean(R.bool.isLarger)) {
                        // Screen is larger, change orientation here
                    } else {
                        // Screen is smaller, perform your action
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you are still not using `NavigationComponent` you can do this check in `fragment` `onCreate()` this way.

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mTwoPane = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (resources.getBoolean(R.bool.isLarger)) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }

        if (mTwoPane) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Larger", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Smaller", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: So where should I check the value of `mTwoPane`? in `onCreate`?

Comment: Yes in fragments onCreate( ). I have added the code at the end of my answer

Comment: `if (mTwoPane) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Larger", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`. This is hot we realize if it's small or large. But still, the screen is laggy and gets stuck in the middle of the rotation.

Comment: I have tested in my pixel 3a and pixel tablet emulator. There is no such lag.

Comment: Did you use the code like this : `activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` ?

Comment: Yes I used that code and did orientation changes, it was completely smooth with no delay at all. It depends on what task you are adding inside it.

Comment: actually my screen doesn't rotate at all with the main activity being locked in portrait mode, and when I delete that part of the code, it lags. but I'm testing it on a weak device.
Since config changes only on `uiMode` the activity isn't recreated at all.

Comment: Okay, seems like the issue right now is about performance and optimizating for devices. You can make other post about it raising specific issue, cause I have answered your question for managing orientation.